# Numpy array concatenation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

In some special cases, array can be concatenated without explicitly calling `concatenate` function. For example, given a 2D array `A`, the following code will yield an identical array `B`:

```
B = np.array([A[ii,:] for ii in range(A.shape[0])])
```

I know this method works, but do not quite understand the underlying mechanism. Can anyone demystify the code above a little bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `A[ii,:]` is `ii`-th row of array `A`.
- The list comprehension `[A[ii,:] for ii in range(A.shape[0])]` basically makes a list of rows in `A` (`A.shape[0]` is number of rows in `A`).
- Finally, `B` is an array, that its content is a list of `A`'s rows, which is essentially the same as `A` itself.

Answer (score 2):

By now you should be familiar with making an array from a list of lists:

```
In [178]: np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])                                                                    
Out[178]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

but that works just as well if it's a list of arrays:

```
In [179]: np.array([np.array([1,2]),np.array([3,4])])                                                
Out[179]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

`stack` also does this, by adding a dimension to the arrays and calling concatenate (read its code):

```
In [180]: np.stack([np.array([1,2]),np.array([3,4])])                                                
Out[180]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

`concatenate` joins the arrays - on an existing axis:

```
In [181]: np.concatenate([np.array([1,2]),np.array([3,4])])                                          
Out[181]: array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

`stack` adds a dimension first, as in:

```
In [182]: np.concatenate([np.array([[1,2]]),np.array([[3,4]])])                                      
Out[182]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

`np.array` and `concatenate` aren't identical, but there's a lot of overlap in their functionality.